# How to validate my textfields input?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have to validate my `textfields`, which must only accept numbers.  I have a `script` to do so, but this is not the problem.  The problem is: I have to put my `script` in a "src" `package` and change my `.jsp` files to a "jsps" `package`.

How can I validate my `textboxes`?

I send my form, but I can't validate my textboxes one by one. I have 50 of them.  In other `.jsp` file I have more.

Comment: Did you change the reference to the scripts in the jsp pages? Was it working before your changes?

Comment: @BatScream yes I changed them. But i think I need to send my form or the name of the textfield (or something) to the .js file to comparate with some funtions... In the funtion i have to check when the user is typing to let (or not) if the can type

Comment: Call your js method on submit event of the form. And write your script inside the method. Got it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use your javascript to submit the form.  Create an input type="button" set the onclick to your javascript method.  Do all of your checks if everything is ok then do document.forms['YourForm'].submit();